# Сброс дефолтных значений у элементов формы

Tags: jquery

Вчера уже задавал этот вопрос, получил пару ответов, но не совсем то что надо было. Надо каким то образом хранить дефолтные значения всех инпутов, и по клику на крестик сбрасывать значения именного того ряда по котором был клик.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось реализовать кое что,но опять же не то что надо.

```
//CANCEL ROW
    $('.for-clone input').focus(function(){
        $(this).closest('.for-clone').addClass('changed');
        var element = $(this);
        var elementVal = element.val();

        element.closest('.for-clone').find('.remove-column .cancel-ico').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            element.val(elementVal);
            $(this).closest('.for-clone').removeClass('active changed').addClass('edited');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть и по-гомосячьи вышло, но делаю так. При загрузке страницы формирую массив массивов со значениями инпутов формы. Получаю такую структуру массива.

```
arrRows
[
    arrInputs
    [
        arrValues
        []
        []
        []
    ]
    arrInputs
    [
        arrValues
        []
        []
        []
    ]
    arrInputs
    [
        arrValues
        []
        []
        []
    ]
]
```

При изменении формы, и затем клике кнопки `reset` определенной строки считываю значение из сформированного масива.

К примеру, кликаю по средней кнопке с индексом рядка 1, соответственно беру три значения из массива `arrRows[1]`.

Код следующий:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>titile</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style>

 </style>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function(){

   var map = $('.row').map(function(i,el){
          return $(':text', this).map(function(i, el){
           return $(this).val();
          });
      });

   console.log(map);
   
   $('.icon-cancel').on('click', function(){
    var index = $(this).closest('.row').index();
    $(this).closest('.row').find(':text').each(function(i){
     $(this).val(map[index][i]);
    });
   });
    
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="rows">
 <div class="row">
  <input class="input" value="Ниссан" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Мазда" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Опель" type="text">
  <input class="icon-cancel" value="reset" type="button">
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <input class="input" value="Гуси" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Коты" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Змеи" type="text">
  <input class="icon-cancel" value="reset" type="button">
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <input class="input" value="Иванушка" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Дурачок" type="text">
  <input class="input" value="Богатыри" type="text">
  <input class="icon-cancel" value="reset" type="button">
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Хорошо если я динамечески добавлю еще несколько рядов? Сразу же после добавления заносить этот ряд в массив map?

Comment: угу, именно так